# Using Android NDK to implement EDSDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, edsdk

I am now doing a final year project of making a remote control of Canon DSLR from Android devices. What I know is that using Android NDK, I will be able to call a function from the EDSDK from the Android application. I'd like to know if Android NDK provides USB communication from the EDSDK to the camera itself. Because the USB communication from EDSDK is used to control the camera using function from the EDSDK.

If not then is there any other approach that I can use to bridge the communication between the Android device and the camera?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options for getting the EDSDK to work on android

1. You have a statically linked build of the EDSDK built for arm/linux
2. You compile the EDSDK with the NDK yourself. It's likely that EDSDK uses libusb, and if so, you'll have to get that compiling under the NDK as well.

If neither of those are possible, a slightly different approach would be to reverse engineer the protocol that it uses to talk to the camera, and then implement that protocol yourself in java, using the [usb host apis](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html) in android 3.0+